# MSAL - userIdentifier versus idToken.oid

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using MSAL to validate a user against Microsoft Azure AD and am getting a valid token back.

The MSAL library is handing me back a `User` object which contains a property called `userIdentifier`.

This is a string, not a GUID.

The documentation says to use a field called `oid` to uniquely identify users across the Microsoft Identity platform.  I have this property available under `User.idToken.oid`.

This value is a GUID as the documentation says.

My question is, what is this `User.userIdentifier` and should I be using this?  I need to know what to store on the database side to tie this local user to an Azure AD user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity's sake it is advised to use the `accountIdentifier` property as it will [always be populated](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/Account.ts), even in the edge cases where `oid` might not be available:

```js
const accountIdentifier: string = idToken.objectId || idToken.subject;
```

More info on [GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1710#issuecomment-635432541).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/Account.ts), there is no userIdentifier, but there is an accountIdentifier.
Could be yours is an older version, in which case this might not be correct for that.

```
// create accountIdentifier
const accountIdentifier: string = idToken.objectId ||  idToken.subject;
```

It is either the oid or sub claim, whichever has a value.
If you want the oid, you should get it from the idTokenClaims property on Account.

Comment: Thanks I will use `oid`.  I am using the Angualr wrapper, which I should have mentioned, located at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular